# how to automatically create an assembly from a part

Tags: solidworks

[image: part file giving cirpattern instructions][image: screen-shot of assembly file.. there isn't anything to see, it's totally ordinary..]something really funky happened [image: successful cirpattern in part (?!? :-D)]recently, trying to track down what actually happened.  I created a sweep on a 3d-sketched path, then mirrored it accross a plane so that the initial sweep and  the mirrored sweep share some of the same volume.  Then I tried to circular pattern the two of them around a central axis.  ordinarily when I try to do this I get the error "only merging features can be patterned".  however, one time doing this, I was researching how to do it, then, on giving up, I clicked something and bada-boom the whole thing worked.  with a catch.  it seemed like solidworks had automatically created an assembly with the same name, imported the part into it, and carried out the operation that I wanted it to do, but in the assembly, not the part.  I swear I didn't do all these  things myself.  now, I'm trying to figure out how it  happened, because, obviously, super useful!

For the record, I've found a work-around. creating a solid surface with which to connect all the sweeps, then sketching the end profile of the sweep on the solid surface fixes the problem, and no assembly is necessary.  so  you could say that this is a superior solution anyway because it avoids the extra file getting generated, but I'm still super curious about the other thing that happened.

Second edit:  I tried to reproduce the error for a commentator.. and.. failed.  it worked!  exactly the way I wanted it to!  Right in the part!  So.. we still have  a mystery, but it isn't clear if it's worth trying to solve..

Comment: It sounds like you should be doing this with a pattern of bodies (instead of features), anyway? Are you mistaking a multibody part for an assembly?

Comment: pretty sure I'm not..  as for bodies vrs features, that  could be..  :-)

Comment: Please can you send a screenshot of the assembly file?

Comment: sure :-)  enjoy! :-)  ..probably more useful (not very?) to send the screen shot of the part file I tried to circlepattern..

Comment: huh.  tried to reproduce the error, and failed!  it worked this time exactly the way I wanted it to!  no workaround, nothing!  ..go figure..  ..I'm almost disappointed.. :-S ;-)  the mystery, to the extent that there is one, is whether or not there is any way that what I previously described could actually happen..

Comment: Maybe you unchecked the "Merge Solids option" - https://forum.solidworks.com/thread/86206  Another work around would just be making an assembly and patterning the part, instead of patterning features within a part file.

Comment: @jko -that is how I was doing it in the past.  I'm getting more sophisticated now though like ~~ ^-^, and trying to get everything as clean as I can, both in number of files, and in time spent :-)   ..merge solids huh?  ... will have to check that.  thanks! :-D

Comment: @jko - this is pretty much what pattern bodies does - but without needing an assembly environment. Solidworks is completely happy with multibody parts, and in many ways they are superior to assemblies. You can use the save bodies feature to generate multiple part files for manufacture at the very end.

Comment: @juggler - I've got lots of comments/tips on how you could improve your life just from a glance at your history tree - I'd be happy to do a screenshare at some point to offer some best practice tips etc. Let me know if so and I'll work out how to get some contact details to you (there's no direct messaging on StackExchange...)

Comment: @JonathanRSwift john, that would be awesome!

Comment: @Juggler - send me a message via https://www.thingiverse.com/messages/compose?username=jonathanrswift and we’ll arrange a time!

Comment: thank you @JonathanRSwift !  .. I'm thinking of posting an answer to my question here and crediting you for having provided it.  maybe tomorrow?

Comment: Sure! Happy to help :)